# Custom metrics in Dynatrace

Tags: java, spring, monitoring, metrics, dynatrace

I want to use the **Dynatrace** monitoring system. I have researched a little monitoring of the **Spring application** using a **Micrometer + Prometheus + Grafana**. In this case, when we creating custom metrics (for example, a counter), we must write in the code, for example:

```
Counter counter = Counter
  .builder("instance")
  .description("indicates instance count of the object")
  .tags("dev", "performance")
  .register(registry);

counter.increment(2.0);
 
assertTrue(counter.count() == 2);
 
counter.increment(-1);
 
assertTrue(counter.count() == 1);
```

I have a question: how can I make custom metric using Dynatrace? I could not find examples of code. For example, I need a custom counter metric. **How can I create this in my Java code?**

Comment: Did you review the official related documentation at https://docs.dynatrace.com/docs/extend-dynatrace/extend-metrics/ingestion-methods/micrometer ? https://www.dynatrace.com/hub/detail/micrometer/ offers even more details. Sources for the implementation seem to be at https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/tree/main/implementations/micrometer-registry-dynatrace